# Inheriting from generic class throws error CS0246 : The type or namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, asp.net-core-mvc

**Tools used**

- ASP.NET Core 6 MVC
- Visual Studio Code

**Description**

I have a generic controller like this, I use to gather all the common attributes and core functions of my controllers. When I try to inherit from it, I get the following error :

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GenericController' could not be found

Can anyone enlighten me about what I'm doing wrong?

**NOTE**: I however can navigate through classes and VSCode can find the reference of my classes.

**Code**

(They're both in the same Controller Folder)

`GenericController`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace my_test_project.Controllers;

public abstract class GenericController : Controller
{
    protected readonly ILogger _logger;
    protected readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    protected readonly HttpClient _client;

    public GenericController(ILogger logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _client = CreateHttpClient();
    }

    private HttpClient CreateHttpClient()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                return true; //For testing purpose only
            };
        Console.WriteLine("HTTP Client initialized");
        return new HttpClient(handler);
    }

    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

`HomeController`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace my_test_project.Controllers;

    [Route("home")]
    public class HomeController : GenericController
    {
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration) : base(logger,configuration)
        {
        }

        [HttpGet()]
        public override async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
```

**What I tried / checked**

- They are in the same namespace
- I tried with the generic syntax ( The T one, injecting it in loggers)
- Changed `GenericController` to **not** `abstract`
- Cleaning the project
- Reloading omnisharp (for Visual Studio Code display purpose)

**EDIT**

**How I get the error**

- `Omnisharp` displays the error on `VSCode` permanently
- When using `dotnet build` , it immediately throws the error.

Comment: It would be easier if you put the whole project up somewhere for other people to download because it seems the problem is somewhere else in the project.

Comment: When  did you meet this error? What is your process like ？

Comment: @tia I sadly can't share this project, but will make a similar anonymized one and share it  !

Comment: @QingGuo I edited the question by adding some informations about how I got the error.